# Flow effect to static water on a isometric city

Tags: unity, c#, sprites, isometric, graphic-effects

Hello everyone I want to give the idea that the river in my city is flowing but I am having an hard time to figure how.

Do you have any idea of what I should look into to?
[image]

Comment: Is your problem in deciding what flowing water should look like in your art style? Or do you have a particular visual effect you want to achieve, and you're just not sure how to implement the effect?

Comment: I just want to give the idea the water in river is moving.

Comment: Add small white ripples

Comment: but it needs to give the idea to be moving . Maybe if I have 2 different sets or ripples and change between them

Comment: And it should be moving all in 1 direction.~

Comment: For what it's worth, at this altitude, you wouldn't be able to see water flowing. But to give that effect, put short waterfalls at intervals.  Our brains will then easily detect which way the water flows (downhill)